# Does std::wstring_convert instances change when they are used?

Tags: function, c++11, constants

I have seen several questions with some contact points with this. But none of the answers have convinced me. I have the following class:

```
   class Foo
    {
    public:

        void bar() const
        {
            wstring unicode_string = m_convertor.from_bytes(string("")); // 1
        }

    private:
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> m_convertor;
    };
```

At this point it compiles.But if I change `Foo::bar()` to be constant...

```
void bar() const
{
    // ...
}
```

it fails with error:

> **... 4 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer ...**

At you can see at point **1** in the code, I'm passing a temporary object to `from_bytes` function, so the only think that can change there is the m_convertor instance it self.

I did the following:

```
void bar() const
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>> convertor;
    wstring unicode_string = convertor.from_bytes(string(""));
}
```

And now all compiles ok, so there is not doubt about who is changing.

Right now I´m working with the non-const version of the function, but would like to know why this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::string_convert::from_bytes` isn't a const member function, and that's what's being flagged. If the state of the converter isn't reflective of the state of `Foo` then you could declare the converter member `mutable`.